# Need of Equity share capital if one has sufficient reserves and surplus?

Tags: shares, equity, balance-sheet

New to stock market correct me if i'm wrong.

[Reliance Industries balance sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC2mw.png) According to my understanding reserves and surplus keep account for profit that a company makes and this money is reserved for future expenses of company.

Equity share capital ==> Capital raised by offering shares at face value to investors for operating company

so why a company like Reliance industries would need to raise equity share capital every year if they are having a excess amount of reserves and surplus ?

And if a company wants to raise money to run it's operations why it is giving shares at face value and not at market value, if company gives shares at market value it will have to issue less number of fresh shares in compared to giving shares at face value and thus promoters stake in percentage will be less reduced ?